# Reduce Page loading time

Tags: headers

am trying to reduce page loading time by flush() php function just before  in header.php wordpress file.

Am using W3TC and CDN so that will work or it will be an unused modification?

Answer (score 0):

W3TC has an option called [Page Cache](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/configuring-w3-total-cache-advance-page-cache-i--cms-21148) that will render all your dynamic pages into static HTML and deliver that instead of rendering the page every page load. This reduces loading time **a lot** and I suggest you turn it on and give it a try.